# Remove div from document of active tab

Tags: javascript, google-chrome, google-chrome-extension

I cannot remove div from document of active tab. I have a option button and when I click it this show popup message as html page. On this page I have button save, and when I click it I want to remove div from html of active tab. I want to do this javascript for chrome browser. I tried that, but it did not work

```
chrome.tabs.getSelected(null, function(tab) {
 chrome.tabs.executeScript(tab.id, {
  code: "removeDiv();"
 });
});
```

How can I remove div element of active page from popup html page ?

Comment: Are you asking for "tabs" permission in the manifest? Do you have the page listed in the permissions section of the manifest?

Answer (score 1):

What error/exception do you have?

Remember that content script is executed in different environment, so you cannot execute JS functions defined in the page/background. You can only operate on DOM content. I think proper way to achieve your goal is:

```
chrome.tabs.getSelected(null, function(tab) {
 chrome.tabs.executeScript(tab.id, {
  code: "body of the function which removes div"
 });
});
```

Comment: I want to change div iner html, ... I have two html , one second was generated from first. My question is How can I change div iner html of first document from second html page, because I'm on second page at the moment.

Answer (score 0):

I would inject a content script into the desired page and then apply a "display: none" style to the div I wish to hide.  You can still do powerful things with content scripts, you could event inject javascript into the heading to load jQuery or any other library you want to use.

Comment: I want to change div iner html, ... I have two html , one second was generated from first. My question is How can I change div iner html of first document from second html page, because I'm on second page at the moment.

Comment: @ManY - Can you clarify what you are asking - I think I understand it as you have 2 pages, and you want to take the inner html of a div from page 2 and update the inner div html on page 1.  If this is correct what you would do is use the chrome.extension.* API to send request, or create a port to communicate with.  When the second page has loaded you can trigger to port connection and send the contents of the inner html to page 1 who can then update the contents of its inner html.

Comment: Yes, you understand my problem... and do you have a sample code to show me how to do this, because I'm new to this, and I spent a lot of time with my mistakes. Please show me a code as how you do that. Thanks.